# bash shortcuts doesn't work in bash

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

Bash has some shortcuts like 
`C-p/n` for previous, next command
`C-a/e` for going to the beginning/end of command
`C-l` for clearing
..
However, in my terminal, on Ubuntu 16.04, these doesn't work. `C-p/n` just has no effect. `C-a/e/l` will print a character `^A, ^E, ^L` to bash.

`C-u`still works.So does the normal `C-d` and `C-c`.

Here is the output of `bind -P`

```
abort is not bound to any keys
accept-line can be found on "\C-j", "\C-m".
alias-expand-line is not bound to any keys
arrow-key-prefix is not bound to any keys
backward-byte is not bound to any keys
backward-char can be found on "\eOD", "\e[D".
backward-delete-char can be found on "\C-h", "\C-?".
backward-kill-line is not bound to any keys
backward-kill-word is not bound to any keys
backward-word is not bound to any keys
beginning-of-history is not bound to any keys
beginning-of-line can be found on "\eOH", "\e[H".
call-last-kbd-macro is not bound to any keys
capitalize-word is not bound to any keys
character-search is not bound to any keys
character-search-backward is not bound to any keys
clear-screen is not bound to any keys
complete can be found on "\C-i".
complete-command is not bound to any keys
complete-filename is not bound to any keys
complete-hostname is not bound to any keys
complete-into-braces is not bound to any keys
complete-username is not bound to any keys
complete-variable is not bound to any keys
copy-backward-word is not bound to any keys
copy-forward-word is not bound to any keys
copy-region-as-kill is not bound to any keys
dabbrev-expand is not bound to any keys
delete-char can be found on "\e[3~".
delete-char-or-list is not bound to any keys
delete-horizontal-space is not bound to any keys
digit-argument is not bound to any keys
display-shell-version is not bound to any keys
do-lowercase-version is not bound to any keys
downcase-word is not bound to any keys
dump-functions is not bound to any keys
dump-macros is not bound to any keys
dump-variables is not bound to any keys
dynamic-complete-history is not bound to any keys
edit-and-execute-command is not bound to any keys
emacs-editing-mode is not bound to any keys
end-kbd-macro is not bound to any keys
end-of-history is not bound to any keys
end-of-line can be found on "\eOF", "\e[F".
exchange-point-and-mark is not bound to any keys
forward-backward-delete-char is not bound to any keys
forward-byte is not bound to any keys
forward-char can be found on "\eOC", "\e[C".
forward-search-history can be found on "\C-s".
forward-word is not bound to any keys
glob-complete-word is not bound to any keys
glob-expand-word is not bound to any keys
glob-list-expansions is not bound to any keys
history-and-alias-expand-line is not bound to any keys
history-expand-line is not bound to any keys
history-search-backward is not bound to any keys
history-search-forward is not bound to any keys
history-substring-search-backward is not bound to any keys
history-substring-search-forward is not bound to any keys
insert-comment is not bound to any keys
insert-completions is not bound to any keys
insert-last-argument is not bound to any keys
kill-line is not bound to any keys
kill-region is not bound to any keys
kill-whole-line is not bound to any keys
kill-word is not bound to any keys
magic-space is not bound to any keys
menu-complete can be found on "\C-n".
menu-complete-backward can be found on "\C-p".
next-history can be found on "\eOB", "\e[B".
non-incremental-forward-search-history is not bound to any keys
non-incremental-forward-search-history-again is not bound to any keys
non-incremental-reverse-search-history is not bound to any keys
non-incremental-reverse-search-history-again is not bound to any keys
old-menu-complete is not bound to any keys
operate-and-get-next is not bound to any keys
overwrite-mode is not bound to any keys
possible-command-completions is not bound to any keys
possible-completions is not bound to any keys
possible-filename-completions is not bound to any keys
possible-hostname-completions is not bound to any keys
possible-username-completions is not bound to any keys
possible-variable-completions is not bound to any keys
previous-history can be found on "\eOA", "\e[A".
print-last-kbd-macro is not bound to any keys
quoted-insert can be found on "\C-v".
redraw-current-line is not bound to any keys
re-read-init-file is not bound to any keys
reverse-search-history can be found on "\C-r".
revert-line is not bound to any keys
self-insert can be found on "\C-a", "\C-b", "\C-c", "\C-e", "\C-f", ...
set-mark is not bound to any keys
shell-backward-kill-word is not bound to any keys
shell-backward-word is not bound to any keys
shell-expand-line is not bound to any keys
shell-forward-word is not bound to any keys
shell-kill-word is not bound to any keys
skip-csi-sequence is not bound to any keys
start-kbd-macro is not bound to any keys
tab-insert is not bound to any keys
tilde-expand is not bound to any keys
transpose-chars can be found on "\C-t".
transpose-words is not bound to any keys
tty-status is not bound to any keys
undo is not bound to any keys
universal-argument is not bound to any keys
unix-filename-rubout is not bound to any keys
unix-line-discard can be found on "\C-u".
unix-word-rubout can be found on "\C-w".
upcase-word is not bound to any keys
vi-append-eol is not bound to any keys
vi-append-mode is not bound to any keys
vi-arg-digit is not bound to any keys
vi-back-to-indent is not bound to any keys
vi-backward-bigword is not bound to any keys
vi-backward-word is not bound to any keys
vi-bword is not bound to any keys
vi-bWord is not bound to any keys
vi-change-case is not bound to any keys
vi-change-char is not bound to any keys
vi-change-to is not bound to any keys
vi-char-search is not bound to any keys
vi-column is not bound to any keys
vi-complete is not bound to any keys
vi-delete is not bound to any keys
vi-delete-to is not bound to any keys
vi-editing-mode is not bound to any keys
vi-end-bigword is not bound to any keys
vi-end-word is not bound to any keys
vi-eof-maybe can be found on "\C-d".
vi-eword is not bound to any keys
vi-eWord is not bound to any keys
vi-fetch-history is not bound to any keys
vi-first-print is not bound to any keys
vi-forward-bigword is not bound to any keys
vi-forward-word is not bound to any keys
vi-fword is not bound to any keys
vi-fWord is not bound to any keys
vi-goto-mark is not bound to any keys
vi-insert-beg is not bound to any keys
vi-insertion-mode is not bound to any keys
vi-match is not bound to any keys
vi-movement-mode can be found on "\e".
vi-next-word is not bound to any keys
vi-overstrike is not bound to any keys
vi-overstrike-delete is not bound to any keys
vi-prev-word is not bound to any keys
vi-put is not bound to any keys
vi-redo is not bound to any keys
vi-replace is not bound to any keys
vi-rubout is not bound to any keys
vi-search is not bound to any keys
vi-search-again is not bound to any keys
vi-set-mark is not bound to any keys
vi-subst is not bound to any keys
vi-tilde-expand is not bound to any keys
vi-yank-arg is not bound to any keys
vi-yank-to is not bound to any keys
yank can be found on "\C-y".
yank-last-arg is not bound to any keys
yank-nth-arg is not bound to any keys
yank-pop is not bound to any keys
```

Comment: Is it really bash which has such shortcuts? Isn't it rather the terminal emulator you are using? Have you for instance checked out _Edit -> Settings -> Shortcuts_ in gnome-terminal?

Comment: First question, yea. Those shortcuts belong to bash, at least according to multiple posts I read online.
Second question, I checked `gnome-terminal`'s shortcuts and they are basically the normal GUI shortcuts (Tabbing, Find, copy, paste .etc).

Comment: I stand corrected. Just tried them in gnome-terminal on my Ubuntu 16.10, and they work fine for me.

Comment: Technically, it's not `bash` to which these shortcuts apply, but to the `readline` library which many tools (which include `bash`) use for user command-line interaction.

Comment: Trying to learn about this topic... ;) @pspencil, can you please run the command `bind -P` and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I downloaded `rlwrap` could that be the reason?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have added the output.

Comment: Can't tell about `rlwrap`, but its description indicates that it can be related. However, my googling keeps pointing me to the command `set -o emacs`. You may want to try that.